# Feeding the output of a function into the same function as a for loop

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, md5

I've created a function to MD5 hash a string, now I'd like to iterate this process numerous times, and each time remove an amount of characters from the hexidecimal hash output before it is 're'-hashed. After spending many hours searching for a way to do this I've looked into the range() function, the map() function, tried to make this work with for loops and nested functions, but I lack the knowledge to ask the right questions. The answer may lie in the **class** feature, but I can't find a way to apply that to my particular problem.

Here's my code below:

```
import hashlib

string = "randomstring"


def hash(string):
    en = string.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()
hash1 = hash(string)[:-10]
print("Hash #1", hash1)

def hash1a(hash1):
    en = hash1.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()
hash2 = hash1a(hash1)[:-10]
print("Hash #2", hash2)

def hash2a(hash2):
    en = hash2.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()
hash3 = hash2a(hash2)[:-10]
print("Hash #3", hash3)

def hash3a(hash3):
    en = hash3.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()
hash4 = hash3a(hash3)[:-10]
print("Hash #4", hash4)

def hash4a(hash4):
    en = hash4.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()
hash5 = hash4a(hash4)[:-10]
print("Hash #5", hash5)

def hash5a(hash5):
    en = hash5.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()
hash6 = hash5a(hash5)[:-10]
print("Hash #6", hash6)
```

I'd like to be able to capture the output of the first `hash` function, modify it by appending `[:-10]` and submit that value back into the `hash` function. Being able to capture this (by using a for loop?) in a list or dictionary would be ideal. I've spent about 5 hours researching this and I've learned a lot. Wish I could do better but really just need some direction on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop, and assign the result of the hash to the variable that you use as the argument to the `hash()` function.

```
def hash_n_times(string, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        string = hash(string)[:-10]
    return string

print(hash_n_times("randomstring", 6))
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you

`def hash(string):
    en = string.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()

def hash_n_times(string, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        string = hash(string)[:-10]
    return string

print(hash_n_times("randomstring", 100))`

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar answered this perfectly but I figured I might add a little bit of explanation to hopefully clear a few things up.

First things first: a function is a great way to do this, but a function is specifically for the purpose of creating executable code blocks you can call.  In your code, the same block of code is used redundantly to create "different" functions that are different only in variable names, not executable code. Thus, while you have the right idea, there should only be one function to do this.

This would be an example, from your code, of your ONE single function, called numerous times:

```
def hash(string):
    en = string.encode()
    hex_result = hashlib.md5(en)
    return hex_result.hexdigest()
```

In order to call this function using a for loop you have two options: slot the for loop into the function so that the function will call itself, like @Barmar said, or vice versa e.g. call the function inside of a for loop.

If you decide to keep your function as is, and not modify it as @Barmar suggested (I would personally go with his modification, but that's me), then you would call that above hash() function within your loop:

```
for _ in range(6):
    string = hash(string)[:-10]
```

Here is a link to Python docs about for loops: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Best of luck, and hope this helps :)